# Getting the Product Attribute Term Permalink in WordPress / WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce with WordPress to build a store of Antique Photos.

I'm using the WooCommerce product attributes feature to store information about an item photographer.

See here for an example, photographer attribute is pulled out in the box on the left http://bit.ly/1Dp999O

The code that pulls out the attribute looks like this:

```
if($attribute['is_taxonomy']) {
  $values=wc_get_product_terms($product->id, $attribute['name'], array('fields' => 'names'));
  echo apply_filters('woocommerce_attribute', wpautop(wptexturize(implode(', ', $values))), $attribute, $values);
}
```

$values looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Photographer 1 )
```

The problem is, how do I get to the permalink for the Photographer which is automatically generated by WordPress and WooCommerce: 
http://bit.ly/1JtwBna

I can't find any documentation for this within WooCommerce, and this seems to be a taxonomy within a taxonomy which goes a bit further than stabdard WordPress, but  I'm assuming this is a fairly standard requirement.  Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: An attribute is not a taxonomy within a taxonomy, it is merely a custom taxonomy.

Comment: Ah, so presumably get_the_terms will work?  Will give that a go and update accordingly

Comment: Yes, most term-related functions should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once you have the attribute term (in this case the photographer's name) you can use [`get_term_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_link) to get the URL. Because the `$product` id isn't passed to the `woocommerce_attribute` folder, I couldn't filter that, but instead create an override of the `product-attributes.php` template. And modified the relevant section to be the following:

```
if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

    $terms = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

    $html = '';
    $counter = 1;
    $total = count( $terms );

    foreach( $terms as $term ){ 

        $html .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" title="Permalink to %s">%s</a>', 
            esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ), 
            esc_attr( $term->name ), 
            wptexturize( $term->name ) 
        );

        if( $counter < $total ){
            $html .= ', ';
        }
        $counter++;

    }

    echo wpautop( $html );

}
```

For some reason, the URL isn't a pretty permalink. It's late and I can't tell if this has to do with my configuration or what exactly, but it is a start.

Comment: I had to enable the archives on the attribute edit screen. flushed the permalinks, and now I have pretty urls.

Comment: also, I used `esc_url` around `get_term_link`, but thats just me nitpicking :). thanks again @helgatheviking for your precious answers!

Comment: You're right, it should be `esc_url()` instead of `esc_attr()`. I'll change that.

Answer (score 3):

This basically does what I require:

```
$terms = get_the_terms($product->id, $attribute['name']);
foreach ($terms as $term){
    echo '<a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $term->taxonomy).'">'.$term->name.'</a>';
}
```

But could do with a bit of refinement for sure.

Comment: Yup, that's pretty similar to what I came up with. `get_the_terms()` and `wc_product_terms()` produce pretty similar results.